# How come whether our endpoint is async or not does not matter for the consumer?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Our project is an ASP.NET Core Web API.

I recently had to change one of our synchronous endpoints to async, and started wondering.

How is it so, that whether our endpoint is async or not does not matter for the consumer?

Isn't the Action the outermost layer of our http server? Or is there a layer that sits outside this, that synchronously waits for the entire action to complete its work, and returns its result?

Sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: Yes, there's something outside, but no, why do you assume it has to wait synchornously?

Comment: Making the endpoint async does not matter for the consumer (I assume consumer is the one making requests to the endpoint). In fact you are not making the endpoint async but the method which gets called when a request to the endpoint is made.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the Action the outermost layer of our http server?

Nope; the framework/library code (whether that is Kestrel, MVC, some middleware, whatever) essentially knows how to call your action, and if the result is awaitable (in particular: `[Value]Task[<T>]`): `await` the action; this then *usually* returns an `ActionResult`, which gets a chance to execute to generate the response - which could again be asynchronous, so *that* is awaited too. There is no need for anything to synchronously wait here - and every effort is made to *avoid* synchronous waits.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the caller? If even my outmost "server" tries to return a Task, and since the caller is an entirely separate application, how does the caller determine whether they should expect a Promise/Task, or an actual value, as response?

Comment: @cheekybanana the external caller has no interest in your technology choices - they're processing HTTP, which ultimately means some kind of socket connection; how *their tech stack* exposes that a: has no relationship to your choice of tech stack, and b: has no relationship to whether your app is written using async vs sync implementations; all they see is bytes on a socket; those bytes should be the same via any mechanism - what changes is how your server produces those same bytes